# Get 2D list value with Point for input (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, list, grid-layout, point

For uni I'm programming this game where there is a grid `int[,] grid;`. I also have this class:

```
public class Point
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;

        public Point(int x, int y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public static Point operator +(Point a, Point b)
        => new Point(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y);
    }
```

Representing points in this grid. Is there a way to access values of this grid using points? So say you want the value of the grid at (2, 3), you would access this by `grid[new Point(2,3)]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `int[,] grid;`, No, you can't.

But, you can wrap `int[,] grid;` with a class and use [Indexer Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/) like this

```
public class GridWrapper
{
    // This is your grid data
    public int[,] Grid { set; get; } 

    // Indexer Property
    public int this[Point point] => Grid[point.x, point.y];

    public GridWrapper(int dim1, int dim2)
    {
        Grid = new int[dim1, dim2];
    }
}
```

Now, this will work

```
var value = grid[new Point(1, 2)];
```

Full example

```
// define a grid
var grid = new GridWrapper(3, 3);

// mock data
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    grid.Grid[i, j] = i + j;

// getting a value using the Indexer Property
var value = grid[new Point(1, 2)];
```

Comment: Thanks! I've implemented it in my program but i have one more question. In this situation, when modifying a value the 'ordinary way' (```grid[x, y]```), i get an error. Is there a way to make both ```grid[x, y]``` and ```grid[point]``` valid?

Comment: You can define another indexer property like `public int this[(int, int) tuple] => Grid[tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2];` and use it like `grid[(1,2)]`, or you can define a `Get(int x, int y)` method in `GridWrapper`, or access it like `grid.Grid[1,1]`